# Getting embedded nul string while reading an excel csv

Tags: r, excel, csv

I'm trying to open an Excel CSV file within R Studio but I get this error:

> Error Is this a valid CSV file? embedded nul in the string: 'C\0a\0m\0p\0a\0g\0n\0e\0_\0N\0o\0C\0a\0r\0a\0v\0a\0g\0g\0i\0o\0_\0C\0o\0s\0t\0o\0>\00'

the file is generated automatically by the Google Ads platform as *Excel csv* and it works normally with Excel but in order to open it on R Studio I have to convert it as .xlsx

is there a way to bypass this or to convert the file without opening it?

otherwise the script which is based upon this file needs a manual passage to convert the source file

Comment: Side note: there is no such thing as an "Excel CSV" file. It's a CSV file, plain and simple.

Comment: I do not understand why it is listed as separate option within the list of available file type then

Comment: It's misleading at best.

Comment: Excel butchers CSV files with its "General" type. It will start converting things you don't want to convert. Maybe they did some things to stop that from happening. Just speculation.

Answer (score 0):

What function are you using to open it? Check your file and see if you have other commas within a column value; this may confuse the function. Also, it is worth trying to use the "Import dataset" option in the environment window within Rstudio. Try to use the readr option and adjust your import options until you have it correct. Check the package RAdwords maybe you can extract your Google Ads information without the CSV exporting step.

Comment: library(readr)
google_error <- read_csv("google_error.csv") 
I'm using the built-in function as you suggested